# Add a marker icon to svg map

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a SVG map of a country and the code looks like below

```
         <svg
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin"
            version="1.2"
            viewBox="0 0 1500 1800"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
              <path
                d="M598.3 1048.7l3.9 67.3 9.7 32.2-0.8 14.5-11.9 11.1-9.5 2.7-5.6 3.4-18.3-3.8-18.9 2.9-16.2-1.3-10.2-16.1-3.8-0.4-4.6-1.7-6.3-8.5-7.7-6.9 1.4 12.9 4 16.7-8.9 15.2-28.5 33.7-7.5-2-8.7 0.2-12.8 8.9-9 2-15.9-2-10 8 3.6-1.1 3.4 1.5 7.8 14.4 6.6 6.2 5.2 7.2-5.3 14.9-9.5 10.2-12.9-7.7-19.8-29.5-12.6-1.1 0.2-8.9 3.2-6.8-3.2-5.6-6.7-16 5-4.7 15.3-2.5 7-7.5 4.8-0.3 4.8-1.2 3.5-5.4 2.5-5.9-5.2-6.5-6.4-6.3-0.1-6.6 1.1-7.9-5.3-6.5-11.3-6.3-3.7-2.6 0.7-8.6-19.1-16.8-5.4-13.6 9.1 1 8-2.4-0.8-2-0.3-3 1.5-2.6 1.9-2.4 1.4-8.9 6.3 0 6.9 4.9 7.5 0.6 0.7-4.7-0.7-4.9 6.5-3.7 6.3 1.1 4.8-2.2-2.7-6.1-3.5-5.6 5.2-1.4 5.3-2.5 9.1 12.6 28 17.6 16.3 1 9.4-10.5-1.5-16.3 2.7-7 6.1-3.7 6.6 2.5 16.4 13.6 12.7-1.9 14-11.5 18.2 0.1 7.3-3.6 5.3 6.7 3.2-1.8 2.9-2.5 4.9-8.2 8.9-1.4 14 1.6z"
                id="LKA2448"
                name="Mahanuvara"
              ></path>
              <path
              d="M600.8 944.1l-0.3 7.4 3.2 10.1 1 8.6-4.3 21.1-4.2 20.9 2.1 36.5-14-1.6-8.9 1.4-4.9 8.2-2.9 2.5-3.2 1.8-5.3-6.7-7.3 3.6-18.2-0.1-14 11.5-12.7 1.9-16.4-13.6-6.6-2.5-6.1 3.7-2.7 7 1.5 16.3-9.4 10.5-16.3-1-28-17.6-9.1-12.6 0.2-4.6 2.5-3.3 0.9-5.4-1.3-5.6-2.2-4.7-2.7-4.4-4.4-9 1.1-9.4 6.2-5.7 1.6-3.8-0.1-4.1 1.3-5.3 0.2-5.2-8.1-7.9-2.4-13.8-1.3-14.9-2.3-3.2-1.6-1.1-0.1-7.7-3-7.7-4.4-7.4-3.1-6.9-3.4-0.9-3.9-2.2-1.1-7.9 2-7.2 9.4-7 14.9-5.5 7.8-9.5 7.1 0.3 5.3 3.5 6.6-4.6 3.2-5.4 3.1-2.1 2.9-1.7-0.3-3.2-1-2 5.7-5.9 4.2-6.5-0.1-8.3 2.5-7.1 4.4 0 3.3 0.9 2.6-1.8 8.6-9.1 5.7-5.1 8.4-4.2 9.3-3.8 3.8 3.8 6.2 6.9-0.2 7.9 2.4 2.6 3.7 1.4 2.9-1.8 0.2-2.9 5.3-2.5 5.1 1.4 7 1.5 6.5 3.9-13.3 13.9-4.3 21.1-1.2 10.2-4.3 18-1.5 3.2-0.8 3.3-12.8 2.8-3 12.3 6 27.1-0.8 8.7 4.3 6.2 11.7 2.6 11.1-4.7 8.8-8 3.8 5.3 6.7 4.2 2-7.8 1-8 23.7 1.7 22.8-4.2z"
              id="LKA2449"
              name="Mātale"
              ></path>
              ...
              ...
          </svg>
```

I would like to add a marker icon on a city denoted by

```
              <path
                d="M598.3 1048.7l3.9 67.3 9.7 32.2-0.8 14.5-11.9 11.1-9.5 2.7-5.6 3.4-18.3-3.8-18.9 2.9-16.2-1.3-10.2-16.1-3.8-0.4-4.6-1.7-6.3-8.5-7.7-6.9 1.4 12.9 4 16.7-8.9 15.2-28.5 33.7-7.5-2-8.7 0.2-12.8 8.9-9 2-15.9-2-10 8 3.6-1.1 3.4 1.5 7.8 14.4 6.6 6.2 5.2 7.2-5.3 14.9-9.5 10.2-12.9-7.7-19.8-29.5-12.6-1.1 0.2-8.9 3.2-6.8-3.2-5.6-6.7-16 5-4.7 15.3-2.5 7-7.5 4.8-0.3 4.8-1.2 3.5-5.4 2.5-5.9-5.2-6.5-6.4-6.3-0.1-6.6 1.1-7.9-5.3-6.5-11.3-6.3-3.7-2.6 0.7-8.6-19.1-16.8-5.4-13.6 9.1 1 8-2.4-0.8-2-0.3-3 1.5-2.6 1.9-2.4 1.4-8.9 6.3 0 6.9 4.9 7.5 0.6 0.7-4.7-0.7-4.9 6.5-3.7 6.3 1.1 4.8-2.2-2.7-6.1-3.5-5.6 5.2-1.4 5.3-2.5 9.1 12.6 28 17.6 16.3 1 9.4-10.5-1.5-16.3 2.7-7 6.1-3.7 6.6 2.5 16.4 13.6 12.7-1.9 14-11.5 18.2 0.1 7.3-3.6 5.3 6.7 3.2-1.8 2.9-2.5 4.9-8.2 8.9-1.4 14 1.6z"
                id="LKA2448"
                name="Mahanuvara"
              ></path>
```

I've tried adding a styled div inside `path` tag but it's not showing. What would be the approach to add a marker icon onto svg map.

Attached image below is a example for what i'm trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: how looks your  marker icon ?

Comment: Marker icon can look like anything. I just want to place something ontop of a city

Comment: @MisterJojo I've attached an image as an example for what i'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like that ?
(I pick the marker from wikipedia -> https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fichier:Map_marker.svg )

```css
#elmSVG  { background-color: #377972; }
#elmSVG > path { stroke: whitesmoke; }
#mIx2    { fill: #ffee00; }
#LKA2448 { fill: #621970; }
#LKA2449 { fill: #e06565; }

#elmSVG use.hoverRED { cursor:pointer; }
#elmSVG use.hoverRED:hover { fill:crimson; }
```

```html
<h2> Map of something...</h2>

<svg id="elmSVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin" version="1.2" viewBox="0 0 1500 1800" >
  <defs>
    <symbol id="markerIcon" viewBox="6 6 354 546" >
      <path d="M182.9,551.7c0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.3S358.3,283,358.3,194.6c0-130.1-88.8-186.7-175.4-186.9
        C96.3,7.9,7.5,64.5,7.5,194.6c0,88.4,175.3,357.4,175.3,357.4S182.9,551.7,182.9,551.7z M122.2,187.2c0-33.6,27.2-60.8,60.8-60.8
        c33.6,0,60.8,27.2,60.8,60.8S216.5,248,182.9,248C149.4,248,122.2,220.8,122.2,187.2z"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>

  <path
    d="M598.3 1048.7l3.9 67.3 9.7 32.2-0.8 14.5-11.9 11.1-9.5 2.7-5.6 3.4-18.3-3.8-18.9 2.9-16.2-1.3-10.2-16.1-3.8-0.4-4.6-1.7-6.3-8.5-7.7-6.9 
    1.4 12.9 4 16.7-8.9 15.2-28.5 33.7-7.5-2-8.7 0.2-12.8 8.9-9 2-15.9-2-10 8 3.6-1.1 3.4 1.5 7.8 14.4 6.6 6.2 5.2 7.2-5.3 14.9-9.5 
    10.2-12.9-7.7-19.8-29.5-12.6-1.1 0.2-8.9 3.2-6.8-3.2-5.6-6.7-16 5-4.7 15.3-2.5 7-7.5 4.8-0.3 4.8-1.2 3.5-5.4 2.5-5.9-5.2-6.5-6.4-6.3-0.1-6.6 
    1.1-7.9-5.3-6.5-11.3-6.3-3.7-2.6 0.7-8.6-19.1-16.8-5.4-13.6 9.1 1 8-2.4-0.8-2-0.3-3 1.5-2.6 1.9-2.4 1.4-8.9 6.3 0 6.9 4.9 7.5 0.6 0.7-4.7-0.7-4.9 
    6.5-3.7 6.3 1.1 4.8-2.2-2.7-6.1-3.5-5.6 5.2-1.4 5.3-2.5 9.1 12.6 28 17.6 16.3 1 9.4-10.5-1.5-16.3 2.7-7 6.1-3.7 6.6 2.5 16.4 13.6 12.7-1.9 
    14-11.5 18.2 0.1 7.3-3.6 5.3 6.7 3.2-1.8 2.9-2.5 4.9-8.2 8.9-1.4 14 1.6z"
    id="LKA2448" name="Mahanuvara"></path>
  <path
    d="M600.8 944.1l-0.3 7.4 3.2 10.1 1 8.6-4.3 21.1-4.2 20.9 2.1 36.5-14-1.6-8.9 1.4-4.9 8.2-2.9 2.5-3.2 1.8-5.3-6.7-7.3 3.6-18.2-0.1-14 
    11.5-12.7 1.9-16.4-13.6-6.6-2.5-6.1 3.7-2.7 7 1.5 16.3-9.4 10.5-16.3-1-28-17.6-9.1-12.6 0.2-4.6 2.5-3.3 0.9-5.4-1.3-5.6-2.2-4.7-2.7-4.4-4.4-9 
    1.1-9.4 6.2-5.7 1.6-3.8-0.1-4.1 1.3-5.3 0.2-5.2-8.1-7.9-2.4-13.8-1.3-14.9-2.3-3.2-1.6-1.1-0.1-7.7-3-7.7-4.4-7.4-3.1-6.9-3.4-0.9-3.9-2.2-1.1-7.9 
    2-7.2 9.4-7 14.9-5.5 7.8-9.5 7.1 0.3 5.3 3.5 6.6-4.6 3.2-5.4 3.1-2.1 2.9-1.7-0.3-3.2-1-2 5.7-5.9 4.2-6.5-0.1-8.3 2.5-7.1 4.4 0 3.3 0.9 2.6-1.8 
    8.6-9.1 5.7-5.1 8.4-4.2 9.3-3.8 3.8 3.8 6.2 6.9-0.2 7.9 2.4 2.6 3.7 1.4 2.9-1.8 0.2-2.9 5.3-2.5 5.1 1.4 7 1.5 6.5 3.9-13.3 13.9-4.3 21.1-1.2 
    10.2-4.3 18-1.5 3.2-0.8 3.3-12.8 2.8-3 12.3 6 27.1-0.8 8.7 4.3 6.2 11.7 2.6 11.1-4.7 8.8-8 3.8 5.3 6.7 4.2 2-7.8 1-8 23.7 1.7 22.8-4.2z"
    id="LKA2449" name="Mātale"></path>

  <use xlink:href="#markerIcon" x="500"  y="950" width="35" height="54"  class="hoverRED" fill="#0000ff" />
  <use xlink:href="#markerIcon" x="550"  y="1040" width="35" height="54" class="hoverRED"  id="mIx2" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks alot. But my marker colors are not changed.

Comment: Yes. But i was able to fix it by adding id="mIx2" to the marker path

Comment: @CraZyDroiD you can set the fill color every where you want, even directly on the path symbol

Comment: Is it possible to change color of the marker on hover. I tried it but the doesn't change

Comment: @CraZyDroiD I have done it with a css class, (I have updated my snippet) you can also use js for this or more